# blogger inline suffix expression

Tags: html, blogger

I'm working on a blogger theme and I'm trying to add a class to a `div` in case the blog is seen via mobile. To be specific: my two classes are: `presentation` and `presentation-mobile`.
Since blogger doesn't allow to use a structure like:

```
if()
  <div class="a">
else
  <div class="b">
```

Because it requests to close the div element inside the if (... for real?)
I was forced to use this string of code which seems not to work... can somebody point out where I'm wrong or suggest the right way?

```
expr:class='&quot;container-fluid presentation&quot; + (data:blog.isMobile? &quot;-mobile&quot;:&quot;&quot;)'
```

the error output is:

> The expression `'"container-fluid presentation" + (data:blog.isMobile? "-mobile":"")'` is not valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the newly introduced `b:class` operator. It is used for adding class to the parent element (including appending class names if class already exists). The code will look like -

```
<div>
  <b:class name='presentation' cond='!data:blog.isMobileRequest'/>
  <b:class name='presentation-mobile' cond='data:blog.isMobileRequest'/>
</div>
```

Also, the reason why `data:blog.isMobileRequest` is preferred over `data:blog.isMobile` is because it will function even if the mobile version of the blog is disabled via Settings

Answer (score 0):

Leave a space around ternary operator `? :` and use `data:blog.isMobileRequest` instead of `data:blog.isMobile`

```
expr:class='&quot;container-fluid presentation&quot; + data:blog.isMobileRequest ? &quot;-mobile&quot; : &quot;&quot;'
```